# Color of images dulled on mobile

Tags: image-processing, joomla, virtuemart

On our site http://eatplaygear.com/gear/tops (Joomla, using Virtuemart for the eCommerce)

The desktop version shows the correct colors for the product images.
But somehow on mobile these images are dulled.

I have tried to web-inspect using a Mac and iPhone to see if maybe the src is pointing to another version of the image. But it isn't, the path is the same as the desktop.

Also tried searching there have been previous issues with Joomla Virtuemart, but to no avail.

Any idea what the issue is and how to solve it?

EDIT:

desktop not virtuemart - http://phorge.com.sg/images/desktop-non-virtuemart.jpg

mobile(android) not virtumart - http://phorge.com.sg/images/mobile-non-virtuemart.png

*notice how the colors match*

desktop virtuemart - http://phorge.com.sg/images/desktop-virtuemart.jpg

mobile(android) virtuemart - http://phorge.com.sg/images/mobile-virtuemart.png

*notice how the images on mobile dull out?*

Comment: Stupid question #1 - It's not just the auto-brightness on the phone is it?

Comment: Images seem fine to me on Android - Chrome

Comment: edited my question. with screenshots now. please tell me how it's a stupid question Roger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK upon doing some trial and errors. apparently it had to do with the color profile when exporting the image. just make sure to use Save for Web if using Adobe softwares and strip the color profile